# Android Studio -- Designer screen blank

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new Android Project in Android Studio 3.1.3 on Windows 7:

- included Kotlin support
- API 15: Android 4.0.3
- Basic Activity

I opened content_main.xml in Design View.  Even though it will have a `TextView` saying "Hello World" by default, this was not shown on the Design screen.  Instead, what I am shown is a blank screen with "android...CoordinatorLayout" text in the center:

[image: Designer View]

My `build.gradle` (Module: app) file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: have you included the following 
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
 in your build.gradle file ?

Comment: TBH, I am very much a beginner at Android Studio. I will Google that and have a look.

Comment: Did you ADD the controls to your layout?

Comment: @Psytho. Yes, also dragged a Button, which is shown when I run the app, but is not displayed on the Design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, there is a problem with the versions of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and `com.android.support:design` referenced, which cause the Designer to fail.     Therefore you need to downgrade from API 28 down to 27 in order to use dependencies of version `27.1.1` for these dependencies.  In `build.gradle` (Module: app):

- Change `compileSdkVersion` to `27`
- Change `targetSdkVersion` to `27`
- Reference `27.1.1` for `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`
- Reference `27.1.1` for `com.android.support:design`

This is how the file will look after you make the changes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Once you make the changes to `build.gradle`, a pop-up will ask you to "Sync Now", if you click on it, then after syncing, your designer will work:

[image: designer]

(If you don't have version 27 of the SDK platform installed, then go to Tools → SDK Manager, and install Android 8.1 (Oreo) -- its API level is 27.